# Sizing of rows and columns

Tags: excel, vba

This code replicates row number 2 and 3 for a defined number of rows below.
What changes to do in the code if i want size of row 2 to be equal to all even numbered rows in excel and size of row 3 to be equal to all odd numbered rows in excel except for row 1.

```
Sub Macro2()

    Dim rRange As Range
    Set rRange = Selection.Rows("2:3")
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim Rng As Integer
    n = rRange.Rows.Count
    Rng = InputBox("Enter number of sessions: ")
    Dim i As Integer
    Rows("2:3").Copy
    For i = 1 To Rng
        ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Range("A1").Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Setting the row height and column width are easy to do but the issue you might have is finding what the size of *all even rows* or the size of *all odd rows*. What happens if Row 3's height is 30 and Row 5's height is 35 - which size should it follow? I think the better thing to do would be work out your logic first, then refine your question to be a bit more specific on how and/or why you want to resize the rows.

Answer (score 0):

Adjusting row height and column width can be done as in these examples:

```
Columns("A:A").ColumnWidth = 15.43
Rows("1:1").RowHeight = 34.5
```

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using `Select` and as stated by Samuel, giving the hegiht to a row is easy, the hard part will be to determine which height to pick. With the info you provided this would do it provided you give `X` and `Y` a value:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Test()

    Dim n As Long: n = InputBox("Enter number of sessions: ")
    'assume you have a sheet called SheetWithNames where you input the worksheet where you are
    'going to work, and that name is written in cell A1, then this line below would take that name.
    Dim SheetName As String: SheetName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetWithSheetNames").Range("A1")
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(SheetName) 'Change SheetName for your sheet name
        'This will take the first available row if all your rows in column A are filled
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To n
            .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Resize(2).EntireRow.Value = .Rows("2:3").Value
        Next i
        n = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        .Rows("2:" & n).RowHeight = 118
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: i want it to pick the size of row 2nd and 3rd at real time.It need not be specified in the code

Comment: what do you wnat to do with the height of rows 2 and 3?

Comment: i want to make all the row's height=118 except for row 1.I don;t want any change to row 1

Comment: @JayWanjari check my edit, it should do what you need.

Comment: can this code be without hardcoding the sheet name?

Comment: @JayWanjari please elaborate... what is your goal? What do you need without hardcoding the sheet name?

Comment: if one of my cell has text Run xyz service
for abc operation .I want to replace xyz from a word from excel.How should i go about it